# Azure API call working in Console App & not in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have an asp.net MVC application which allows a user to upload a PDF/image onto the system. I then want to send this PDF onto the Azure Read API and store the returned text in a .text file on the system (so I can later enter some of the data into a database).

I have it working perfectly while testing it in a Console Application, although I can not get it to work when I try implement it into my MVC web app; when I upload a PDF, the file gets uploaded although nothing else happens i.e. no text file is created with the returned data. When I try this with the same Azure API methods in a Console App it works fine (file is created with the returned text)

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Upload()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                string filepath = @"C:\Users\35385\source\repos\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\Surveys\" + filename;
                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Surveys"), filename));
                AzureVisionAPI.ExtractToTextFile(filepath);


                return View();
            }
```

My Azure API call helper methods:

```
namespace BookingSystem.Helpers
{
    static class AzureVisionAPI
    {
        static string subscriptionKey = ("SUBSCRIPTON_KEY");
        static string endpoint = ("END_POINT");

        public static ComputerVisionClient Authenticate(string endpoint, string key)
        {
            ComputerVisionClient client =
                new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key))
                { Endpoint = endpoint };
            return client;
        }


        public static void ExtractToTextFile(string filename)
        {
            ComputerVisionClient client = Authenticate(endpoint, subscriptionKey);
            ExtractTextLocal(client, filename).Wait();
        }

        public static async Task ExtractTextLocal(ComputerVisionClient client, string localImage)
        {

            // Helps calucalte starting index to retrieve operation ID
            const int numberOfCharsInOperationId = 36;

            using (Stream imageStream = File.OpenRead(localImage))
            {
                // Read the text from the local image
                BatchReadFileInStreamHeaders localFileTextHeaders = await client.BatchReadFileInStreamAsync(imageStream);
                // Get the operation location (operation ID)
                string operationLocation = localFileTextHeaders.OperationLocation;

                // Retrieve the URI where the recognized text will be stored from the Operation-Location header.
                string operationId = operationLocation.Substring(operationLocation.Length - numberOfCharsInOperationId);

                // Extract text, wait for it to complete.
                int i = 0;
                int maxRetries = 10;
                ReadOperationResult results;
                do
                {
                    results = await client.GetReadOperationResultAsync(operationId);

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    if (maxRetries == 9)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Azure API timed out");
                    }
                }
                while ((results.Status == TextOperationStatusCodes.Running ||
                        results.Status == TextOperationStatusCodes.NotStarted) && i++ < maxRetries);

                // Display the found text.
                var textRecognitionLocalFileResults = results.RecognitionResults;
                foreach (TextRecognitionResult recResult in textRecognitionLocalFileResults)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\35385\source\repos\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\surveytest.txt"))
                    {
                        foreach (Line line in recResult.Lines)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(line.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely seeing an async deadlock here. Instead of using `.Wait()` you should await the `Task` returned from your async method.

What happens is at your first `await` the method returns, to the method that then calls `.Wait()`, this blocks the thread and has exclusive access to your current `SynchronizationContext`, when the inner awaited thing completes, the following code is queued up on the same `SynchronizationContext`, which is blocked. The `.Wait()` will never stop blocking because the `Task` can never complete. This is know as an async deadlock.

The best way to deal with it here is make your controller async and return `Task<ActionResult>`, then use async/await top-to-bottom. Another way to handle this is to scatter `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to all of your `Task` you `await`, however it's best to just not block when dealing with asynchronous work.

Your code might look like:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Upload()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                string filepath = @"C:\Users\35385\source\repos\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\Surveys\" + filename;
                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Surveys"), filename));
                await AzureVisionAPI.ExtractToTextFile(filepath);


                return View();
            }
```

AzureVisionAPI:

```
namespace BookingSystem.Helpers
{
    static class AzureVisionAPI
    {
        static string subscriptionKey = ("SUBSCRIPTON_KEY");
        static string endpoint = ("END_POINT");

        public static ComputerVisionClient Authenticate(string endpoint, string key)
        {
            ComputerVisionClient client =
                new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key))
                { Endpoint = endpoint };
            return client;
        }


        public static async Task ExtractToTextFile(string filename)
        {
            ComputerVisionClient client = Authenticate(endpoint, subscriptionKey);
            await ExtractTextLocal(client, filename);
        }

        public static async Task ExtractTextLocal(ComputerVisionClient client, string localImage)
        {

            // Helps calucalte starting index to retrieve operation ID
            const int numberOfCharsInOperationId = 36;

            using (Stream imageStream = File.OpenRead(localImage))
            {
                // Read the text from the local image
                BatchReadFileInStreamHeaders localFileTextHeaders = await client.BatchReadFileInStreamAsync(imageStream);
                // Get the operation location (operation ID)
                string operationLocation = localFileTextHeaders.OperationLocation;

                // Retrieve the URI where the recognized text will be stored from the Operation-Location header.
                string operationId = operationLocation.Substring(operationLocation.Length - numberOfCharsInOperationId);

                // Extract text, wait for it to complete.
                int i = 0;
                int maxRetries = 10;
                ReadOperationResult results;
                do
                {
                    results = await client.GetReadOperationResultAsync(operationId);

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    if (maxRetries == 9)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Azure API timed out");
                    }
                }
                while ((results.Status == TextOperationStatusCodes.Running ||
                        results.Status == TextOperationStatusCodes.NotStarted) && i++ < maxRetries);

                // Display the found text.
                var textRecognitionLocalFileResults = results.RecognitionResults;
                foreach (TextRecognitionResult recResult in textRecognitionLocalFileResults)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\35385\source\repos\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\surveytest.txt"))
                    {
                        foreach (Line line in recResult.Lines)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(line.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. Could you please include an example of how I can do this please? I am not familiar async deadlock

Comment: Done, it should just be a case of changing the controller

Comment: Thanks buddy. I am getting an error: Cannot await 'void'

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks for your time and good explanations. I will have to look into learning async controllers

Comment: No worries :) Glad I could help